# apache ant - No source files and no packages have been specified

Tags: java, ant

I tried to learned apache ant by this tutorial [Apache Ant - tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheAnt/article.html)

but after I created step by step build file and run it throws:

```
compile:
    [javac] /home/nazar_art/workspace/de.vogella.build.ant.first/src/test/build.xml:27: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
jar:
      [jar] Building MANIFEST-only jar: /home/nazar_art/workspace/de.vogella.build.ant.first/src/test/dist/de.vogella.build.test.ant.jar
docs:

BUILD FAILED
/home/nazar_art/workspace/de.vogella.build.ant.first/src/test/build.xml:34: No source files and no packages have been specified.
```

I can't understand why this happened?
I use Ubuntu 12.04 OS, and Eclipse Indigo.

***build.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
  <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />

  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    </javac>

  </target>

  <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\de.vogella.build.test.ant.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

***Code part:***

```
package math;

public class MyMath {
  public int multi(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 * number2;
  }
} 

package test;

import math.MyMath;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyMath math = new MyMath();
    System.out.println("Result is: " + math.multi(5, 10));
  }
}
```

- How to solve this trouble?

Comment: It works fine for my configuration: Ant 1.9.4 / Java 1.8.0 on Windows. Javadocs are generated for all classes in both packages.

Answer (score 0):

In your ANT build.xml the `<docs>` target is trying to generate documentation for "src" package. Try with the correct package name like "math" in `<javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="...">` like `packagenames="math,test"`. You can read the [ANT documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) which has examples of `javadoc` task usage.

Comment: this doesn't help `33: No source files and no packages have been specified.`